# Why is the Jewel Voice Broadcast called that?

Tags: world-war-two, japan

I can't seem to find out the reason behind the naming of the audio [Jewel Voice Broadcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewel_Voice_Broadcast).

I learned that this broadcast was the first instance of the Emperor directly communicating to masses. I can speculate that perhaps this had something to do with the naming. Or perhaps the voice of Emperor was called so in veneration. Or maybe it's just a transliteration of Gyokuon-hōsō (which still begs the question why it was compared with Jewels).

Comment: I have also seen _玉音放送_ translated as "Jade Voice Broadcast" in some histories of the war (e.g. S. C. M. Paine's _The Japanese Empire_).  I believe the first symbol,_玉_, can have a number of meanings, including 'gem', 'jewel', and 'jade'.  I've always assumed _玉音_, or 'Jade Voice', was just a way of euphemistically referring to the Emperor's voice.  It will be interesting to see whether anyone can come up with a definitive answer.

Comment: "the war situation has developed not necessarily to Japan's advantage" - the emperor was quite a smooth talker it seems... :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Jewel Voice" is most likely an overly-literal translation of 玉音放送. A better translation might be "(The) Emperor's Voice".

The 玉 character means "jade", which can also be translated as "jewel". But jade has special significance in Japanese culture, often associated with royalty and divinity. In ancient Chinese history, which had a big influence on Japanese culture, many divine rituals involved jade; the prime deity of Daoism is the [Jade Emperor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jade_Emperor).

This usage carried over into Japan, where the voice of the Emperor can also be called 鹤音 or "Crane's Voice" - the crane also has special significance in Japanese culture.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Wikipedia's internal page on citogenesis (see no. 7)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_citogenesis_incidents), the specific origin of the mistranslation in congusbongus's answer is from a Wikipedia edit in 2006. From there, use of the term skyrocketed and created a situation were that translation was kept as it was now apparently supported by reliable sources (citogenesis). This was caught in September 2021 and fixed.